# How to get 2nd array in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am creating a route in node.js

and this is my code:

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
      getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
        results.contacts=contacts;
          res.json(results);
      }); 

  }else{
        res.json(results);
  }
});
```

the output in my browser is like this  :

```
"schedSetting":{
"id":59,
"sched_date":"2016-03-03 09:03:00",
"agenda":"meeting",

},
"contacts":[
{
"id":218,
"accountcode":"",
"extentype":0,

},

}
]
}
```

How can i remove the **schedSetting** array so that my output will only be the **contacts** array like this :

```
"contacts":[
    {
    "id":218,
    "accountcode":"",
    "extentype":0,

    },

    }
    ]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what about `delete(results['schedSetting'])` ?

Comment: What is inside variale `results` server side in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the `contacts` instead of `results` variable:

```
res.json(contacts);
```

Full code:

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
      getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
        results.contacts=contacts;
          res.json(contacts);
      }); 

  }else{
        res.json(results);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
delete myObject.myKey; 
// or 
delete myObject['myKey']; 
// or 
var myProp = "myKey"; 
delete myObject[myProp]
```

If you interest in reading about it [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)